# PHP exec(MSAccess.exe MS_access_file.accdb) possible?

Tags: php, ms-access, iis

I'm am trying to open a MS Access database from a webpage. I am not trying to connect to the database, simply to make it run. When I run the code below I can see MS Access open but the database is not outputting anything

I don't know enough about php to know if this is possible or not.

This is on a test  intranet and have set the accdb to full control permissions on IIS_IUSRS.  The purpose of the database is to print out forms on a printer hanging off of the server to cut down on staff errors.

There is an autoexec macro that executes a VBA module in the database. It does read in the value from the text file so the accdb knows how many copies to print.

I am not getting any feedback from the code, and not finding anything in windows event viewer either.

Is it possible to open a database on the server?   I can run it on the server by running the accdb, but exec(accdb), shell_exec are not working.

Side note: the domain that these are going to is listed in localhost on the server and the PCs that are trying to work with it.  The domains are not actual domains on the Internet.
Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>  
    <br><br><center>
    <h3>Enter the number of copies you would like to print :</h3>
    <form action="printit.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print">
</form>
    </center>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['field1'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'];           
    $ret = file_put_contents('d:\\OneDrive\\Intranet\\www.foo-intranet.com\\db\\NumberofCopies.txt', $data, LOCK_EX);   

    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error here.');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }

    }

  $backtome = exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSAccess.exe" D:\\OneDrive\\Intranet\\www.foo-intranet.com\\db\\Reports_printer2.accdb');
    if(isnull($backtome)) {
        echo 'There was a null in exec command.';
    }
    else{
        echo '$backtome received from exec';
    }

    ?>  

    <br>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

When manually running the accdb, it prints to the printer perfectly

Comment: You cannot "execute a MS Access database" from PHP or any other way - its a data file. You need to execute Microsoft Access and tell it which database to open.

Comment: Correct, but I am calling the MS Access and then the database, I can see MS Access running for a minute in task mgr but I get no output from the database